# Read a json file and grep a string from matching pattern using bash

Tags: json, bash

I am trying to parse below big json file using bash

```
//part of json file
{"name": "Jenkins", "version": "Jenkins-2.22"},
{"name": "FitNesse", "version": "FitNesse-2.1"},
{"name": "Quint","version": "Quint-2.12"},
{"name": "Otto","version": "Otto-1.0"},
{"name": "Gradle","version": "Gradle-1.1"}
```

I am able read the line matching 'version' from json file

```
while read line; do
  if [[ $line =~ "version" ]] ; then
    echo $line; fi
done < $manifestfile
```

I want to store the values[Jenkins-2.22, FitNesse-2.1, Quint-2.12, Otto-1.0, Gradle-1.1] in array in my while loop

need help with tweaking my above code

Comment: Any reason you can't use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)?

Comment: is array mandatory? does the array need to processed after all?

Comment: yes @RomanPerekhrest all these tools version are displayed in different webpage (ex wiki.tools.com) once I have the version stored in an array then I can pass each array element and run seacrh against my wiki page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the sample input above is inside a JSON *array* in file `file.json`, i.e.:

```
[
  {"name": "Jenkins", "version": "Jenkins-2.22"},
  {"name": "FitNesse", "version": "FitNesse-2.1"},
  {"name": "Quint","version": "Quint-2.12"},
  {"name": "Otto","version": "Otto-1.0"},
  {"name": "Gradle","version": "Gradle-1.1"}
]
```

<sup>Note: The only change required to make the commands below work in **Bash 3.x** too is to replace `readarray -t versions` with `IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -ra versions`</sup>

#### Using Bash 4.x and [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

**`jq`** must be installed first, but that's well worth the effort, if feasible: it **enables sophisticated, robust JSON parsing**.

```
# Extract the version numbers and read them into a Bash array.
readarray -t versions < <(jq -r '.[].version' file.json)

# Print the array.
printf '%s\n' "${versions[@]}"
```

The above yields:

```
Jenkins-2.22
FitNesse-2.1
Quint-2.12
Otto-1.0
Gradle-1.1
```

---

#### Using Bash 4.x and `awk`:

If you cannot install `jq`, the following `awk` solution is an alternative, but note that it is **much less robust and relies on the JSON to be formatted exactly as above**.
This warning applies to *any* solution using standard utilities (`awk`, `grep`, `sed`, ...) - **only a dedicated JSON parser will work *robustly***.

```
readarray -t versions < <(awk -F\" 'NF>1 { print $(NF-1) }' file.json)

# Print the array.
printf '%s\n' "${versions[@]}"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -n 's/.*"\([^"]*\)"}.*/\1/p' <file>
```

Answer (score 1):

[***jq***](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is a proper tool to manipulate JSON data in Unix shell.

Let's say `test.json` file contains:

```
[
{"name": "Jenkins", "version": "Jenkins-2.22"},
{"name": "FitNesse", "version": "FitNesse-2.1"},
{"name": "Quint","version": "Quint-2.12"},
{"name": "Otto","version": "Otto-1.0"},
{"name": "Gradle","version": "Gradle-1.1"}
]
```

***test_json.sh*** script (simplified version):

```
#!/bin/bash
versions=$(jq '.[] | .version' test.json)
versions_arr=($versions)  # contains an array of `version` key values
```

---

I must ***warn*** that the above approach `($versions)` (creating an array upon string splitting) may ***fail*** if the string `$versions` has *globbing* characters in it.

---

The more "steady" approach would be using built-in `read` command with `-a` option to read the data wordwise into the specified array:

***test_json.sh*** script ("steady" version):

```
#!/bin/bash
versions=$(jq '.[] | .version' test.json)
read -a versions_arr <<< $versions  # read `version` key values into array
```

Now, `versions_arr` is an array of `version` key values.
 
To print for e.g. the second array value you would do:

```
echo ${versions_arr[1]}
```

The output:

```
"FitNesse-2.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JQ for parsing your Json easily, just install JQ, then use :

if you have a json array, and in every element you have the field version, you can use :

```
 cat myJsonFile | jq '.[].version'
```

That will return a list of versions

If you want to process line by line use

```
while read line; do
  if [[ $line =~ "version" ]] ; then
    echo $line | jq .[] | jq ."version" ; fi
done < $manifestfile
```